# Persist a variable to use in Having clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT 
    Monitor_Summary.Company_id AS CompanyId, 
    Monitor_Summary.Company_Name,
    COUNT(1) AS Total,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) 
     FROM MONITOR  
     WHERE ISNULL(MONITOR.IPWarning_ind, 0) = 1
       AND MONITOR.Company_id = Monitor_Summary.Company_ID
       AND MONITOR.Status_ind NOT IN (1,0)) AS NewWarnings      
FROM 
    Monitor_Summary
GROUP BY 
    Monitor_Summary.Company_id, Monitor_Summary.Company_Name
HAVING 
    COUNT(1) > 2 AND NewWarnings > 1
```

I want to only select rows which have more than 1 NewWarnings. I am getting a error saying invalid column and not sure how to fix this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your basic query inside a subquery or a CTE so that you can refer to the `NewWarnings` column:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        Monitor_Summary.Company_id AS CompanyId, 
        Monitor_Summary.Company_Name,
        COUNT(1) AS Total,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) 
         FROM MONITOR  
         WHERE ISNULL(MONITOR.IPWarning_ind, 0) = 1
           AND MONITOR.Company_id = Monitor_Summary.Company_ID
           AND MONITOR.Status_ind NOT IN (1,0)) AS NewWarnings      
    FROM 
        Monitor_Summary
    GROUP BY 
        Monitor_Summary.Company_id, Monitor_Summary.Company_Name
)
SELECT 
    CompanyId, 
    Company_Name,
    Total,
    NewWarnings      
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    Total > 2 AND NewWarnings > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT` is evaluated *only after* `HAVING` has been executed. Hence you cannot use `NewWarnings` in the `HAVING` clause.

One way to work around this problem, is to implement the correlated subquery of the `SELECT` clause using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT Monitor_Summary.Company_id AS CompanyId, 
        Monitor_Summary.Company_Name,
        COUNT(1) AS Total,
        x.NewWarnings
FROM Monitor_Summary
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT COUNT(1) 
   FROM MONITOR  
   WHERE ISNULL(MONITOR.IPWarning_ind, 0) = 1
         AND MONITOR.Company_id = Monitor_Summary.Company_ID
         AND MONITOR.Status_ind NOT IN (1,0)
) AS x(NewWarnings)
WHERE x.NewWarnings > 1
GROUP BY Monitor_Summary.Company_id,Monitor_Summary.Company_Name
HAVING COUNT(1) > 2
```

This way you can use `NewWarnings` field in the `WHERE` clause of your query.